# Views Self left outer Join Query Bad Performance it is taking long time in SQL

Tags: sql-server-2012

Could anyone advice on how do I improve the performance of the following query. Note, the problem seems to be caused by Left outer join condition clause.

```
    ALTER VIEW [dbo].[CustomerAccountRelatedAccounts]
AS
SELECT        
    ca.AccountNumber, ca.ShipTo, ca.SystemCode, cafg.AccountNumber AS RelatedAccountNumber, cafg.ShipTo AS RelatedShipTo, 
    cafg.SystemCode AS RelatedSystemCode
FROM dbo.CustomerAccount AS ca 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.CustomerAccount AS cafg 
        ON ca.FinancialGroup = cafg.FinancialGroup 
            AND ca.NationalAccount = cafg.NationalAccount
            AND cafg.IsActive = 1
WHERE CA.IsActive = 1
GO
```

Here's the execution plan; https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HJ7_N-9cQ

Comment: Looks like you probably need to check your indexes to me. Could you gather the actual execution plan, paste it into pastetheplan.com and then update your question to include the link?

Comment: How to check indexes? Currently i dont have permission in prod.

Comment: The best way is to look at the actual execution plan.

Comment: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HJ7_N-9cQ

Comment: Could you please check my execution plan in above link?

Comment: wait, why are you re-linking to the same table twice? your IsActive=1 flags make that redundant. You're linking on the same fields so that self join is unnecessary. I'd suggest taking out the join altogether and just use the base table fields.

Comment: ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CustomerAccount] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_CustomerAccount] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 [AccountNumber] ASC,
 [ShipTo] ASC,
 [SystemCode] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

Comment: The reason is one AccountNumber tie up with multiple relatedAccount Number that's why they are mapped same table